# folder permission for uploading files in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I am desperate with this issue, I set all the permissions correctly (I think), but I still can't upload file on the server. I am receiving error that access is denied when I am trying to upload the file.
I set the permissions to be able to write for Internet guest, network service and asp.net in both physical folder and in the iis.
What am i missing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File uploads are processed by the ASP.NET machine account.  You should just need to give the ASP.NET machine account R/W permissions on the folder on the file system and in IIS.  What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: it says: Access to the path 'folder path' is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an AppPool for your site and run it as a user that has permission to R/W to the desired directories.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I provided write permission to deployed folder for IUSR and IIS_IUSRS

[image]